# Как создать условие на выполнение кода при изменении выбранного элемента из выпадающего списка?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```
<code><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<select name="gorod" id="gorod" data-options="500" data-option="0" data-name="Тарифы">
    <option value="95" name="Промо" id="promo"> Промо </option>
    <option value="194" name="Стартовый" id="starter">Стартовый</option>
    <option value="387" name="Бизнес" id="biznes">Бизнес</option>
    <option value="618" name="Корпоративный" id="coop">Корпоративный</option>
    <option value="3300" name="Колл-центр" id="callcentr">Колл-центр</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
 if (document.getElementById("gorod").options[2].selected=true;){
         $( "#polzunok-1" ).slider({ 
    value: 10;
     }
    });

 $("#polzunok-1").slider({
     value: 0,
     min: 3,
     max: 50,
     step: 1,
     slide: function(event, ui) {
       $("#amount1").val(ui.value);
       polzunok1Price = ui.value;
       updatePrice();
     }
   });
</script>
</code>
```

Нужно, чтобы срабатывала эта часть кода при выборе конкретного элемента из списка:

```
$( "#polzunok-1" ).slider({ value: 10;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#gorod").change(function(e) {
  if (this.options[2].selected) {
    $("#polzunok-1").slider({
      value: 10
    });
  }
});

$("#polzunok-1").slider({
  value: 0,
  min: 3,
  max: 50,
  step: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#gorod")[0].selectedIndex = Math.floor((ui.value - 1) / 10);
  }
});
```

```css
#polzunok-1 {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<select name="gorod" id="gorod" data-options="500" data-option="0" data-name="Тарифы">
  <option value="95" name="Промо" id="promo"> Промо </option>
  <option value="194" name="Стартовый" id="starter">Стартовый</option>
  <option value="387" name="Бизнес" id="biznes">Бизнес</option>
  <option value="618" name="Корпоративный" id="coop">Корпоративный</option>
  <option value="3300" name="Колл-центр" id="callcentr">Колл-центр</option>
</select>
<br/>
<div id="polzunok-1"></div>
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста как вытащить, значение $("#polzunok-1"), если необходимо из менять уже сам выбранный элемент списка на следующий  при переходе значения?